# Docker files persist through different images

Tags: docker

This has become really infuriating. I had a docker image, example:.

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install jsvc && \
    cd /home && \
    wget http://apache.mirror.vu.lt/apache//commons/daemon/source/commons-daemon-1.1.0-native-src.tar.gz && \    
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

I decided that I don't want to download the archive anymore, changed dockerFile to:

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN yum update -y 

CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

When I run this new image, it's container still has archive in home directory (even though it's a new container). How is this possible?

I thought maybe a volume is cached or something like, and tried creating completely new image (same dockerFile though).

The archive is still in home directory.

I tried removing cache with `system prune`, but it still does not help.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I am using Visual Studio Code docker plugin to build and run dockers.

Docker build command:

```
docker build --rm -f "guardian\centos\DockerFile" -t percepta:kernel-guardian-centos guardian\centos
```

Docker run:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5001:5001/tcp percepta:kernel-guardian-centos
```

Comment: Please include the exact steps taken, including the commands run and their output, showing your new Dockerfile, build command, and docker run command.

Comment: Did you rebuild the image after changing the dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using `system prune` was not enough, needed to add `-a` to remove everything, not only dangling images and cache.

After that, everything worked as expected (though I need to rebuild everything else, which is not ideal), but since it's development environment, it will suffice.

Side note: 
When building image, console output tells me that it's using cache, even though I am building different image (different name, same dockerfile):

Example:.

```
Step 5/5 : CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> af02f66ccf44
```

Maybe this causes issues?